# automatic cropping of images according to height width given in img tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, crop

In my website on listing pages I have to show small thumbnail of images which are used in detailed pages and they are larger in size. SO to display thumbnail in listing i am scaling them with height and width in `<img>` tag.

I know this is never good idea. because it makes page heavy and  it takes time to load.

Is there any way that images get automatically cropped according to given height width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't crop things client-side to make them lightweight because all the heavy lifting is already done (transferring the files). Not to mention it would be very intensive for your end users to be doing image manipulations. You will need to create thumbnails server side. You should post a question detailing what server side technology you are using (C#, php, etc). Ideally you would cache them or create them ahead of time so that you only do it once and save your server from unneeded work too.

Actually, don't post a followup question on what server side tech you are using. This has been asked a ton of times on SO. Search for how to do it. `php thumbnail creation` for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you have PHP available, you can try [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/), which does all that for you and much more.  It can crop, zoom-crop, transform, blur, contrast...etc etc, and it auto-creates the thumbnails and keeps them in cache so it doesn't have to re-crop...etc each time the image is loaded.

It's also VERY simple to install and use, which is a big plus.